# gem PgSearch find a wrong client by name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pg-search

I have a strange exceptional error. And I don't know why it happened. Can you help me and describe what I did wrong?

I have a simple pgsearch.

## client.rb

```
pg_search_scope :search,
   against: %i[name phone_number],
   associated_against: {
    month_payments: [:payment_note],
      addresses: %i[address_1 town state zip_code]
      },
    using: { tsearch: { prefix: true, any_word: true } }
```

Here's my console output:

```
c = Company.find(172)
c.clients.search(name: "Vasja B")
=> [#<Client id: 2210, company_id: 172, name: "Client 2", email: "", variety: "residential", created_at: "2019-07-23 13:19:36", updated_at: "2019-07-24 11:48:19", phone_number: "", organisation: "", office_note: "", special_note: "", status: "active", mowing: true, landscaping: false, fertilizing: false, leaf_removal: true>]>

2.5.3 :016 > c.clients.count
(1.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."company_id" = $1  [["company_id", 172]]
=> 2 

2.5.3 :017 > c.clients.last
Client Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE 
"clients"."company_id" = $1 ORDER BY "clients"."id" DESC LIMIT $2  [["company_id", 172], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Client id: 2210, company_id: 172, name: "Client 2", email: "", variety: "residential", created_at: "2019-07-23 13:19:36", updated_at: "2019-07-24 11:48:19", phone_number: "", organisation: "", office_note: "", special_note: "", status: "active", mowing: true, landscaping: false, fertilizing: false, leaf_removal: true> 

2.5.3 :018 > c.clients.first
Client Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."company_id" = $1 ORDER BY "clients"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["company_id", 172], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Client id: 2209, company_id: 172, name: "Client 1", email: "", variety: "residential", created_at: "2019-07-23 13:19:11", updated_at: "2019-07-24 11:48:19", phone_number: "", organisation: "", office_note: "", special_note: "", status: "active", mowing: true, landscaping: false, fertilizing: false, leaf_removal: false>
```

Why pgsearch find a Client 2 instead of not existing record? :)

Answer (score 0):

Your indexes may need to be [rebuilt](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#rebuilding-search-documents-for-a-given-class)

The documentation lists scenarios where they might get out of sync along with commands on how to rebuild them.

```
$ rake pg_search:multisearch:rebuild[Client]
```

Comment: rake pg_search:multisearch:rebuild[Client]
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "pg_search_documents" does not exist
LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"pg_search_documents"'::r...

Comment: Can you run it with `Company` first, instead of `Client` and see if you see the same error?

Comment: I tried 
Company.first.clients.search(name: "Vasja B") 
and it's return 15 records...

Comment: I mean the rake task: `rake pg_search:multisearch:rebuild[Company]`. The error you posted as a response makes me think there's either a migration missing or a `pg_search_scope` configuration issue